# How to take screenshot on test error using pytest selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, screenshot

I have pytest hoook that takes screenshots on test failure. For the tests with **failed** status selenium takes a screenshot.
However, when the test fails inside pytest fixture the test status is **error**, and selenium does not take a screenshot.
How to take a screenshot when a test fails on a fixture?

This is a pytest hook that takes screenshots on test failure.

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()

    if report.when == "call":
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            time.sleep(1)
            DRIVER.save_screenshot(screenshot_file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're only checking if the report was generated during the `call` phase, which is the test function.

Including the `setup` phase, which is any fixture executed before your test, should solve the issue --

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()

    if report.when in ("setup", "call"):
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            time.sleep(1)
            DRIVER.save_screenshot(screenshot_file)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you please advise me where I can find more information on different phases like "setup"?

Comment: glad it worked! I recommend referring to the pytest api docs  -- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html 
If we search for the `makereport` hook, we get a `TestReport` as a return object. Looking at the `TestReport.when` attribute (as referred to in your code) we can see all the available options. Hope this helps!